# Splitting a string but preserving the deliminator in C

Tags: c

I want to split a string by alphabetic characters. I started with `strtok`

```
char str[] = "A89 99B0 C11D98 9";
char delim[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

char *ptr = strtok(str, delim);

while(ptr != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
}
```

but I need to preserve the deliminator. Something like

```
A89 99
B0 
C11
D98 9
```

I doubt if it is doable by `strtok`, and I should look for another approach (e.g., regex).

One possible solution I thought of is to insert a non-alphanumeric deliminator before each alphabetic character in the string, and then use `strtok` for this deliminator.

Comment: try strpbrk or strcspn depending if you want a pointer or an index back.

Comment: If you are not getting rid of any characters you can't do it in place because there is nowhere to put the terminator for each string - unless you know absolutely for sure that the source array is big enough to expand the string by inserting them.  So you will have to either 1) have a function that returns the size needed so you can ensure it is big enough before calling the split function or 2) have a split function that splits in place if the buffer is big enough or allocates the space if not - but then you need a way to signal to the caller which one was used so they can free the memory.

Comment: So if the split function takes an input buffer and an output buffer and returns the size you could pass a NULL output buffer to get the size and then pass the input buffer as both if the size was big enough (kind of like how sprintf does) or if the split function takes an input buffer and a pointer to an output buffer you could pass a NULL as the output buffer pointer and the function could do it in place if there is space or make an output buffer and pass it back if there wasn't - then if the pointer to output buffer is NULL it was done in place (the return would be the pointer to the string)

Comment: @JerryJeremiah good points for devising a new approach.

Comment: Here is a possible way to do it: https://onlinegdb.com/4upvpivar

Comment: @JerryJeremiah wow that's sophisticated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing with the data, as it's quite possible you don't need to construct actual strings.  If you can avoid copying the data to include the null terminators, it may be useful.  eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char str[] = "A89 99B0 C11D98 9";
char delim[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

int
main(void)
{
        char *ptr = str;
        while( *ptr ){
                size_t next = strcspn(ptr + 1, delim) + 1;
                fwrite(ptr, 1, next, stdout);
                putc('\n', stdout);
                ptr += next;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using the results from `strtok` as a mask over a full copy of the string?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   
    char str[] = "A89 99B0 C11D98 9";
    char delim[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    char *str_dup = strdup(str);

    if (str_dup != NULL)
    {
        char *ptr = strtok(str, delim);

        while(ptr != NULL)
        {
            int field_len = strlen(ptr) + 1;
            char *field_start = str_dup + (ptr - str) - 1;

            printf("%.*s\n", field_len, field_start);

            ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }

        free (str_dup);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a string traverse, have a try

```
// Pseudocode
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
    if (isalpha(str[i])) printf("\n");
    printf("%c", str[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is print the characters to the screen then you can just iterate through the string and print bits, but if you need to actually tokenise the string so that you can use it later you have two choices (which I mentioned in the comments):

1. If you want to do a strtok type of tokenization where you end up with a NUL terminated string containing NUL terminators between the individual pieces then you can either do it in-place or make a new string.  In order to decide, you need to know the size of the new string that will be created.  Then, if the original string's buffer is big enough you can do it in-place and if it isn't either the caller can allocate something big enough and pass that in instead.  To measure the size of the new string you could use the same trick as sprintf and if the output string is a NULL pointer you can return the size and if it is not you can just fill it in.
2. You could skip the measure step and have the function decide internally if the input string had space or not.  You would pass a NULL pointer as the output string and the function would do it in-place if it could and the output pointer would remain NULL or it would allocate the space needed and the output pointer would point to the new string.  The function could return the output string either way which might be more useful than returning the size as the return value and the caller would know if it had to free the space based on the value of the output pointer.
3. If you wanted the tokenised output as an actual array of strings, you could always pass a NULL pointer as the output buffer and have the function allocate all the pieces internally.  The caller would always have to free the pieces because there is no option to do it in place.

This example shows how I would do #1:

```
// if output is not NULL this will take an input and a delimiter
// and construct a NUL terminated set of NUL terminated strings into output
// and return the size of the whole thing
//
// if output is not NULL this will only calculate how much space would be used
// and then return the size of the whole thing
long tokenise(char *output, char *input, char *delimiters)
{
    long length, size = 0;
    char *next, *current = input, *destination = output;
    
    while(next = strpbrk(current+1,delimiters))
    {
        length = next-current;
        if(destination) // if we aren't just measuring
        {
            if(output == input)
                strcpy(destination+length+1,next++); // if we are doing it in-place
            else
                strncpy(destination,current,length); // if we are making a new string
            destination[length] = '\0';
            destination += length+1;
        }
        size += length+1; // +1 = single NUL
        current = next;
    }
    
    length = strlen(current);
    if(destination) // if we aren't just measuring
    {
        if(output != input)
            strncpy(destination,current,length); // if we are making a new string
        destination[length] = '\0';
        destination[length+1] = '\0';
    }
    return size+length+2; // +2 = double NUL
}
```

And to iterate through, printing the strings:

```
char *pointer = output;
while(*pointer)
{
    puts(pointer);
    pointer += strlen(pointer)+1;
}
```

Try it at https://www.onlinegdb.com/4upvpivar

And reusing the same tokenise function from above you can do #2 like this:

```
char* onesteptokenise(char **output, char *input, long input_max, char *delimiters)
{
    long size = tokenise(NULL,input,delimiters); // measure the size
    if (size<=input_max)
    {
        // do it in place
        *output = NULL;
        tokenise(input,input,delimiters);
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        // make a new string
        *output = malloc(size);
        if (*output) tokenise(*output,input,delimiters);
        return *output;
    }
}
```

Try it at https://onlinegdb.com/IW_h9hiNV